# ZF2.4 File input RenameUpload

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form2

I have got a fieldset implementing `InputFilterProviderInterface`, so it has the function `getInputFilterSpecification`. The `__construct()` function is adding a file element ('logo') like so:

```
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'logo',
        'type' => 'file',
        'attributes' => array(
            'required' => false,
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'id' => 'logo',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Company Logo: ',
        ),
    ));
```

In my `getInputFilterSpecification` function how do I add the RenameUpload input filter?

I have tried several variations of the following without success:

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification()
{
    return array(
        
        array(
            'name' => 'logo',
            'filterchain' => array(
                'name' => 'filerenameupload',
                'options' => array(
                    'target' => '/public/images/' . time(),
                ),
            ),
            'required' => false,
        ),
        //... other filters
    }
}
```

How do I add the FileRenameUpload filter (`Zend\Filter\File\RenameUpload`)?

### [edit]

I have changed the array to:

```
        array(
            'name' => 'logo',
            'filters' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'filerenameupload',
                    'options' => array(
                        'target' => '/public/images/' . time(),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'required' => false,
        ),
```

Which "appears" to be working, however I am now getting this message -

> File 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpDA68.tmp' could not be renamed. An error
> occurred while processing the file.

What errors could have occurred? How do I fix it?

Comment: I assume you (or apache) don't have permission to rename file in C:\xampp\tmp

Comment: With that in mind, I have set `ini_set('upload_tmp_dir',realpath (__DIR__ . '/../tmp/'));` in my index.php file, however when I do an upload it is still saying the tmp folder is in the xampp directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is being caused by specifying an invalid `target`. Prefixing it with `getcwd()` makes the path relative to the application root.

```
array(
    'name' => 'logo',
    'filters' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'filerenameupload',
            'options' => array(
                'target' => getcwd() . '/public/images/' . time(),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'required' => false,
),
```

Comment: Would you also have a hint/solution as to how to fix the related problem in your question edit? `File 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpDA68.tmp' could not be renamed. An error occurred while processing the file.` (It is the bit for which I'm currently looking for a solution in my application ;) )

Comment: I had done something silly and was trying to call `isValid` twice. The first `isValid` worked fine, renaming the file. The second call failed as the file with that name no longer exists - it had been renamed. Silly me.

Comment: Ah thx, fallen for that one myself before as well ;-) I'll keep searching then, my issue is not that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You must have created dir before use renameFile.

Example:
mkdir( $rootPath . '/public/images/' . time() );